# Selecionar maior valor por linha de duas colunas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho um dataframe com diversas colunas, as duas ultimas são onde eu faço soma e multiplicação das outras colunas, no final eu crio uma coluna que deve selecionar o maior valor dentre essas duas colunas, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acabei fazendo um 'FOR' para percorrer cada linha, mas como é um dataframe grande, acaba demorando muito.

Existe alguma outra maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Tente isso: `df['soma_final'] = df.loc[:, ['soma1', 'soma2']].max(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.apply()`.

```
def max_value(row):
    return max(row['soma'], row['multiplicacao'])

df['max'] = df.apply(max_value, axis=1)
```

A função apply aplica uma função a cada linha (quando axis = 1) ou a cada coluna (quando axis = 0). Eu não testei a solução então não sei se terá diferença na performance.